# django form max_length does not work

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using django 1.8.7. I noticed that max_length for form is not working. The form validates even when the max_length is set and password length is more than 50 for following code. Though the min_length validation works fine.

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    email_mobile = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="Email or Mobile")
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, label="Password", min_length=6, max_length=50, error_messages={'min_length': 'Password should be at least 6 characters long.'})
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput, required = False)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(AuthenticationForm, self).clean()
        try:
            if 'email_mobile' in self.cleaned_data:
                int(self.cleaned_data['email_mobile'])
                if len(self.cleaned_data['email_mobile']) != 10:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("Please provide a valid 10 digit mobile number.")
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            if 'email_mobile' in self.cleaned_data:
                validate_email(self.cleaned_data['email_mobile'])

        return self.cleaned_data
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug ?

Comment: Not related, but your `clean()` method should use `cleaned_data` not `self.cleaned_data`, also your `return` has the wrong indentation.

Comment: How are you rendering the form?

Comment: Paste a chunk of your view dealing with the form.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I was using the form input which already had set 50 maxlength characters in html and when I sent keys using selenium , it did not take more than 50 characters.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.PasswordInput) it takes only one argument: `render_value`. Also, the constructor does not have any other parameters as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#PasswordInput

Try cleaning it up in form clean up. Also if you are going to store it in CharField in the model, it would serve your purpose.